# Different values of "this" in event handlers

Tags: javascript, this

Consider this piece of TypeScript code which relies on the JQuery library:

```
class Alpha {
    public foo() {
        $('.ca').click(() => {console.log(this)});
        $('.cb').click(function () {console.log(this)});
    }
}
```

Assume that `$('.ca')` and `$('.cb')` refer to two buttons.

After calling `foo` on an Alpha object, we see that the click handler for '.ca' prints the Alpha object, whereas the click handler for '.cb' prints the button identified by `$('.cb')`.

Both of these different interpretations of `this` can be useful. But what do I do if I want to use *both* versions of `this` inside a handler? In other words, I want to access both the Alpha object and the '.cb' button inside the handler.

**EDIT**

To clarify: I should have emphasized that I'm specifically interested in a way to access the '.ca' button in the situation where I'm using the `=>` notation.

User Matt U indicated this in his answer to my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: I have replaced `typescript` tag with `javascript` tag because this question is not related to typescript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `event` object with the arrow function to get the element (e.g. the button with class `.cb`) that triggered the `click` event, while `this` will refer to the class. Such as:

```js
class Alpha {
  foo() {
    $('.cb').click(event => {
      console.log(this);
      console.log(event.target.className);
    }
  }
}
```

See [here](https://codepen.io/meubin10/pen/LYzryrK?editors=1010) for a working example.

Answer (score 1):

Why it works like that can be answered with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work).

TLDR : Inside event handlers, `this` is the element on which the event is attached. All function types (except arrow functions), `this` depends on how they are invoked and belong to the invoker. Arrow functions take `this` from the lexical scope of their declaration (Here the object instance).

You can keep a reference of the `this` in another variable, and taking advantage of closures use that inside your event handler.

```
class Alpha {
    public foo() {
        let context = this;
        $('.ca').click(function () {
        console.log(context); console.log(this); });
    }
}
```